# Align Captions of 2 figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, vertical-alignment

I managed to get my two Tikz figures side by side. The vertical alignment of the Tikz figures is fine and needs to stay that way. However, I am bothered by the captions and I'd like both of them to be at the bottom.

```
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
  \minipage{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Styles
  \tikzstyle{main}=[minimum size=5mm, very thick, draw=black!100]
  \tikzstyle{bolt}=[circle]
  \tikzstyle{connect}=[-latex, thick]
  % Bolts
  \node[main,bolt] (s)   at (0.0, 0.0) [label=above:Bolt S] { };
  \node[main,bolt] (t)   at (1.5, 0.0) [label=above:Bolt T] { };
  % lines
  \draw (s) edge [connect] (t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Cap 1}
  \endminipage\hfill
  \minipage{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  % Styles
  \tikzstyle{main}=[minimum size=5mm, very thick, draw=black!100]
  \tikzstyle{bolt}=[circle]
  \tikzstyle{connect}=[-latex, thick]
  % Bolt S
  \node[main,rounded corners=10pt] (S) [label=above:Bolt S] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [main,bolt] (ai) at (0.0, 1.5) {};
      \node [main,bolt] (aii) at (0.0, 0.0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  % Bolt T
  \node[main,rounded corners=10pt,right=of S] (T) [label=above:Bolt T] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [main,bolt] (bi) at (0.0, 3.0) {};
      \node [main,bolt] (bii) at (0.0, 1.5) {};
      \node [main,bolt] (biii) at (0.0, 0.0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  % Connect
  \draw (S) edge [connect] (T);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Cap 2}
  \endminipage
  \end{figure}
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: It's strange to use two captions inside the same figure environment. It's better to use sub figures.

Comment: @Sigur I'll give Subfigures a try now. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Sigur I found the solution. I modified `minipage` to align at the bottom and am using an invisible grid to even out the size. Furthermore, I adjusted the relative positioning in the first graph, so it's similar to the right one:

```
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
  \minipage[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Styles
  \tikzstyle{main}=[minimum size=5mm, very thick, draw=black!100]
  \tikzstyle{bolt}=[circle]
  \tikzstyle{connect}=[-latex, thick]
  % fake
  \draw[step=0.25cm,color=white!20] (0,-2) grid (0,2);
  % Bolts
  \node[main,bolt] (s) [label=above:Bolt S] { };
  \node[main,bolt,right=of s] (t) [label=above:Bolt T] { };
  % lines
  \draw (s) edge [connect] (t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Cap 1}
  \endminipage\hfill
  \minipage[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  % Styles
  \tikzstyle{main}=[minimum size=5mm, very thick, draw=black!100]
  \tikzstyle{bolt}=[circle]
  \tikzstyle{connect}=[-latex, thick]
  % fake
  \draw[step=0.25cm,color=white] (0,-2) grid (0,2);
  % Bolt S
  \node[main,rounded corners=10pt] (S) [label=above:Bolt S] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [main,bolt] (ai) at (0.0, 1.5) {};
      \node [main,bolt] (aii) at (0.0, 0.0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  % Bolt T
  \node[main,rounded corners=10pt,right=of S] (T) [label=above:Bolt T] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [main,bolt] (bi) at (0.0, 3.0) {};
      \node [main,bolt] (bii) at (0.0, 1.5) {};
      \node [main,bolt] (biii) at (0.0, 0.0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  % Connect
  \draw (S) edge [connect] (T);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Cap 2}
  \endminipage
  \end{figure}
```

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

Cheers! And thanks again to Sigur!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
fooooo
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
foooooooo
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the Tikz figures do not have the same size, therefore, this will mess up the vertical alignment :(

Comment: Oh, I see. You want the horizontal arrows aligned. Try to fake the highest object from the right figure on the left one. You can draw it in white colour or use `\path` instead of `\draw`.

Comment: @Sigure I used a grid to do that now. Thanks! Maybe change your answer to incorporate the `[b]` and the invisible grid, so I can mark yours correct :)

Comment: @user2033511, great! I'll delete it. You can answer your own question with the solution.